# Discrete uniform RV proof

Tags: probability

There are $10$ numbered toys in a box: $3$ trucks (numbered as $1$, $2$ and $3$),
$1$ doll (numbered as $4$), $2$ cars (numbered as $5$ and $6$), $2$ cubes (numbered
as $7$ and $8$) and $2$ balls (numbered as $9$ and $10$). We select a toy at random
from the box and observe its number. Assume that each toy has the same
probability of being selected. Let $X$ be the observed number. Prove that $X$
is a discrete uniform random variable.

Comment: Hint: what e.g. is the probability that $X=3$?

Comment: Your sample space consists of the set of numbers from 1 to 10, inclusive. Each number has the same probability. So.....

Answer (score 1):

The number of possible results of your experiment is given by $n(\Omega) = \binom{10}{1}$, and you have only one item with each number, so

\begin{align}
P(X=x) = \frac{\binom{1}{1}}{\binom{10}{1}} = \frac{1}{10}, \,\, \forall x\in\{1,2,...,10\}\,.
\end{align}
Hence, $X \sim DU[1,10]$.